# js-cookie enzyme testing fails on testing cookie.set function

Tags: reactjs, js-cookie

I am trying to unit test js-cookie
My code is like this

```
import Cookie from 'js-cookie'

onChange (e) {
    Cookie.set('locale', e.target.value)
    window.location.reload()
  }
```

and for unit testing I am doing this

```
describe('LocaleDropDown', () => {
  const handleLocaleChange = sinon.spy()
  const Cookie = sinon.spy(Cookie,'set')

  it("when simulating a change, Cookie.set should be called", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<LocaleDropDown onChange = {handleLocaleChange}/>)
    wrapper.find('select').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'en'}})
    expect(Cookie.set.calledOnce).toBe(true)
  });
```

})

It fails saying ReferenceError: Cookie is not defined

How should I be testing js-cookie

Answer (score 3):

You must import the library also inside your unit test, add this line to your test and you'll be fine.

```
import Cookie from 'js-cookie'
```